# automatically set certain filetype's file format to unix

Tags: vim

How can I let vim automatically set the file format as UNIX for certain filetypes? For example if I create a `script.sh`, and I want vim automatically set the file format to UNIX, now it's DOS.

Comment: What does that mean? Line endings in the text?

Comment: @uchuugaka I am saying vim file format http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`, put the following:

```
if &modifiable
    setlocal fileformat=unix
endif
```

Alternatively, you can also configure this via an explicit `:autocmd` in your `~/.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType sh if &modifiable|setlocal fileformat=unix|endif
```

(But I would recommend using the provided abstractions to avoid cluttering your vimrc file.)

Comment: Can I somehow set it in the vimrc?